# Handling Latin1 and UTF8 Encoding in Image Attribute Parameters

Tags: python, utf-8, encode, iso-8859-1, stable-diffusion

I am working with the [stable diffusion webUI library](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) and trying to use oiio to read the attribute parameters of images that the library generates. The encoding conventions of this library seem to be a mix of Latin1 and UTF8.

oiio code:

```
ImageBuf inp;
...
const ImageSpec& spec = inp.spec();

OIIO::ustring parameters;
spec.getattribute("Parameters", TypeString, &parameters);
```

For example, I have noticed that one of space character encoded as %C2%A0 in UTF8 is encoded as %A0 in Latin1. When I pass a Latin1 encoded string containing this space character to the JSON module for processing, it crashes.

I would like to know how I can handle this situation. Is there a way to convert the Latin1 encoded strings to UTF8 before passing them to JSON? Or is there any way I can find out what its code is?

I am relatively new to Python and appreciate any guidance on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: That code looks like C++ to me, not Python...

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for your reply. yes its C++, I mean the source code for the stable diffusion webUI is Python